# Out of memory loading a 390k md2 model

Tags: android, memory-management, opengl-es

Anyone know what limits are for models loaded in android?

390k seems awfully small for limitations.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The in memory size of the parsed md2 can be larger then the file size.  There will be some overhead with the in memory data structures.  Also the md2 format compresses the animation frames.

Comment: how much memory is there to work with... should I remove animations not being used to lower the memory needed?